# how to create different row group of different employees with same name in AG-grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Grouping employees by their names but employees with same name are also grouping together.
i want group them according to their Id but don't want to show Id in grid.

[{ Id: 1, employee: John}, { Id: 2, employee: John }, {  Id: 3, employee: John },]

how i can group them according to their Ids.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your id be unique?
Anyway you can make use of a prop `keyCreator` in your columnDef of that group.

```js
const columnDefs = [
  {
    field: 'Id',
    rowGroup: true,
    // Create groups from Id key
    keyCreator: ({ value: Id }) => {
      if (Id > 2) {
        return 'Greater'
      } else {
        return 'Some other group'
      }
    },
  }
  // Other columnDefs.....
]
```